# What are the different capabilities of the uncommon infected in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I don't mean the Spitter, Boomer, etc.
I mean the uncommon infected on every campaign, like the Hazmat Suits (that drop Bile Bombs) and Clowns (that you can honk their noses to get an achievement).

What are the rest, and what's unique about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are called Uncommon Infected, and a full list of which they are and what's special about them is available [here](http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/Common_Infected#Uncommon_Infected).
To summarise:

- Infected CEDA Workers (haz-mat suits)
- Jimmy Gibbs Junior (more health, fireproof)
- Fallen Survivor (has a lot of random gear like molotovs)
- Clown Infected (honk attracts infected)
- Mud Men (hard to see, sprinters)
- Worker Infected (easy to spot, immune to bile and pipebombs)
- Riot Infected (have armour on the front)

Comment: hey cool, I didn't realise Jimmy Gibbs Junior was an uncommon. Also, the worker infected are immune to pipe-bombs as they have the earmuffs.

Comment: Should possibly edit Mud Men to say that they aren't slowed by water, as opposed to calling them sprinters (given that normal infected sprint when they know you are around)...?

Comment: They're faster overall, not just in the water. It's just meant as a summary anyway, the link has a more elaborate description.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that honking from clowns attracts more zombies.
The suited zombies are fireproof.
The Riot police zombies are harder to kills, they also drop Batons and are very effective at halting survivors.

The rest I cant tell you cause Im not at home at the moment.